# Why does my div scroll above the title when scrolling?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #000;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.tabsWraper {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.contents {
  margin-left: 25%;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
  bottom: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="title">
    BLOOD BANK MANAGEMENT SYETEM
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <ul class="tabsWraper">

      <li class="tabs">
        <a class="active" href="#">Add Person</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tabs">
        <a href="#">New Donation</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tabs">
        <a href="#">New Recieve</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tabs">
        <a href="#">Check Stock</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="contents">
      cfgcggfcgfcggf
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have this code in my project.

When I scroll the webpage, the contents inside the `.contents` pass through the title which was not expected. Can someone tell a suggestion to fix this problem? I have tried using `z-index` property but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
*{
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                border: none;
            }
            .title{
                text-align: center;
                color: red;
                font-size: 30px;
                padding: 20px;
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #000;
                position: -webkit-sticky;
                position: sticky;
                top: 0;
                background-color: beige;
            }
            .tabsWraper {
                list-style-type: none;
                width: 25%;
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
                position: fixed;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            .contents{
                margin-left:25%;
                padding:1px 16px;
                height:1000px;
                bottom: 2000px;
            }
```